# Maximum likelihood estimate geometric

Tags: probability

I am studying for a future test and I am slightly puzzled by how this answer is obtained, could someone give me a detailed step by step solution which I will hopefully understand.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the observations $x_1$, $x_2$,..,$x_n$ are independent, the joint likelihood is given by the product of their identical distributions
$$\begin{align}P(X=x_1,X=x_2,..,X=x_n|\Theta)&=(1-\Theta)\Theta^{x_1}\times(1-\Theta)\Theta^{x_2}\cdots\times(1-\Theta)\Theta^{x_n}\\&=(1-\Theta)^n\Theta^{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k}\end{align}$$
Taking the logarithm results in
$$\log P(X=x_1,x_2,..,x_n|\Theta)=n\log(1-\Theta)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)\log \Theta$$
Differentiating the log likelihood with respect to $\Theta$ gives
$$\frac{\partial\log P(X=x_1,x_2,..,x_n|\Theta)}{\partial\Theta}=-\frac{n}{1-\Theta}+\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)\frac{1}{\Theta}$$
Setting the derivative to $0$ and solving for $\Theta$ gives
$$\Theta=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k}{n+\sum_{k=1}^nx_k}=\frac{\overline{x}}{1+\overline{x}}$$
where $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ is the mean of the samples.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the very first line? How you got from the expression in the question to your first line.

Comment: I have elaborated further on the first line, to help explain.